# Want excel userform to populate a specific range in the next blank row

Tags: vba, excel

first time posting here. I am trying to have my userform values fill in the next "blank row", but the row won't truly be blank. The range I want the userform to fill will be blank, but the first column and last 2 columns of the sheet will have formulas.
for example, "A", "D" and "E" will have formulas already in them, I need my userform to populate "B" and "C". I hope that makes sense.

```
Private Sub Add_Click()
'Copy input values to sheet.
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Risk&Opp")
lastRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws.Range("B" & lastRow).Value = ComboBox1.Value
ws.Range("C" & lastRow).Value = ComboBox2.Value
ws.Range("D" & lastRow).Value = TextBox1.Value
ws.Range("E" & lastRow).Value = TextBox2.Value
ws.Range("F" & lastRow).Value = ComboBox4.Value
ws.Range("G" & lastRow).Value = ComboBox5.Value
ws.Range("H" & lastRow).Value = Me.ComboBox6.Value
ws.Range("I" & lastRow).Value = Me.ComboBox7.Value
ws.Range("J" & lastRow).Value = Me.ComboBox8.Value
ws.Range("K" & lastRow).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
ws.Range("M" & lastRow).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
ws.Range("O" & lastRow).Value = Me.ComboBox9.Value
ws.Range("P" & lastRow).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
ws.Range("Q" & lastRow).Value = Me.TextBox6.Value
```

Here I have formulas in A,R, and S. I would like my userform to see if the range B:Q is blank, and if so, assign those values from the userform.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your first check. Can carry the logic down for each check needed

```
IF ws.Range("B" & lastRow) <> "" Then ws.Range("B" & lastRow) = ComboBox1.Value
```

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through the cells in the last row to check if each one is blank. If not, do the same with the next row until you find the first row in which all cells from column B to Q are blank.

Here is the code:

```
Sub test()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rowFilled As Boolean

Set ws = Sheets("Risk&Opp")
lastRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Set boolean to true
rowFilled = True

'Count rows until you find a row where range B:Q is blank
While rowFilled = True
    rowFilled = False

    'Loop from column B (index 2) to column Q (index 17)
    For i = 2 To 17

        'If one of the cell is not blank increase lastrow
        If ws.Cells(lastRow, i) <> "" Then
            rowFilled = True
            lastRow = lastRow + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
Wend

'The first row with blank range B:Q
MsgBox lastRow

'...Add your existing code here...

End Sub
```